# Default method implementation without virtual dispatch

Tags: c++

Ok, so I think I'm trying to have my cake and eat it, too. I don't think this is possible, but here we go.

I'm working on a simple event system, where the callbacks are defined in some user-define listener class, and the event emitter takes that class as a template argument. The reason for taking a template arg is that I want to avoid having the listener methods being called using virtual dispatch.

```
// Class in charge of emitting events.
template<typename TListener = DefaultEmptyListener>
class Emitter {
public:
    Emitter(TListener& l) : mListen(l) {}

    EmitFoo(...) {
       mListen.OnFoo(...);
    }

    EmitBar(...) {
       mListen.OnBar(...);
    }
private:
    TListener& mListen;
};

class SomeUserDefinedListener() {
   void OnFoo() {} // Not virtual
   // OnBar(); --> Not defined. Want default implementation.
}
```

My issue is that I want to avoid having the user have to define 'On*' methods for all the possible events. That is, I want the listener class to have default implementation of the event methods, if the user didn't provide a method.

Is there a way to give the listener default implementations without introduction virtual dispatch into the mix?

Comment: Instead of events being implemented as methods, each event should be a class of its own. Then, each "listener" has overloaded OnEvent() method implementing each particular event, and perhaps a templated onEvent() that serves as a catch-all for all other events.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - That's way more heavy than I need it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `virtual` when you're dealing with objects whose exact type is known at compile time (i.e. no dynamic dispatch).  Just create a base class with default implementations of all the handler methods, and a derived class that overrides the handler(s) you want to customize, and pass the derived class as the template parameter.

If you want to be able to pass the *base* class as the `TListener` template parameter, but then have the `mListen` variable actually refer to instances of derived classes, then you need to declare the handler functions as `virtual`.  But if `TListener` is always going to be the exact type of the object that `mListen` refers to, you don't need `virtual`.

(BTW, "virtual inheritance" is something different than plain virtual functions, which I think is what you were referring to.)

Comment: I find it, somewhat, disturbing that this crossed my mind for the briefest second, and I thought "Nah, that would work.", and I didn't even try it. This is so straight forward that I now feel bad for not having, immediately, known the answer. I've been programming in C++ for about 15 years, and I've written compilers for various languages. I'm questioning my life right now. Also yeah, I meant virtual functions, not virtual inheritance. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

You might use inheritance without virtual polymorphism:

```
// Class in charge of emitting events.
template<typename TListener = DefaultEmptyListener>
class Emitter {
public:
    Emitter(TListener& l) : mListen(l) {}

    EmitFoo(...) {
       mListen.OnFoo(...);
    }

    EmitBar(...) {
       mListen.OnBar(...);
    }
private:
    TListener& mListen;
};

class SomeUserDefinedListener() : public DefaultEmptyListener {
   void OnFoo() {} // Not virtual
   // OnBar(); --> Not defined. DefaultEmptyListener implementation.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it quite easily in C++17, utilising `if constexpr` and the [detection idiom](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4502.pdf) (where `ns::is_detected` is `std::experimental::is_detected` or similar)

```
// Class in charge of emitting events.
template<typename TListener = DefaultEmptyListener>
class Emitter {
public:
    Emitter(TListener& l) : mListen(l) {}

    EmitFoo(...) {
        if constexpr (ns::is_detected_v<decltype(mListen.OnFoo(...)>>)
        { mListen.OnFoo(...); }
        else
        { /* Default empty behaviour */ }
    }

    EmitBar(...) {
        if constexpr (ns::is_detected_v<decltype(mListen.OnBar(...)>>)
        { mListen.OnBar(...); }
        else
        { /* Default empty behaviour */ }
    }
private:
    TListener& mListen;
};
```

This can be backported to C++14 / C++11 with normal SFINAE methods.